# How to move image up and down continuously using translate animation in android?

Tags: android, animation

I have successfully done one side animation using `Translate Animation` means the image goes from top to the bottom. Here is the code:

```
private ImageView mScanner;
private Animation mAnimation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mScanner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Scanner);

    mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 500);
    mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
    mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    mScanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Now I want that when image reaches to the bottom of the screen, it should start moving back to the top. How can I do that?

Note: Done the reverse mode. Please see the code. But now problem is that, it leaves lines when moving from bottom to top. Like the attached image. How to remove this lines?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: View my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38934624/2535875

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Modify your code according to this:

```
   mScanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f);
   mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
   mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
   mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
   mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
   mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

And moreover use xml rather than image. Please see the below code and put it in your `ImageView` src.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="#0000FF"/>
    <size android:width="480dp"
        android:height="10dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Perfect. I included the xml and remove `mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);` the line and it worked as I wanted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sandy I checked this code from 2.1 to 4.2 and its working in my all devices. Please do not try to use image as I was having problem with image and then I used `XML` based created line as a replacement of image used in project. Kindly check your code and try one more time. Thanks

Comment: It shows what it should, but just so you know, if you use it on a camera view, it can affect the performance a lot. On a nexus 3 for example, the camera would have like a 1 second lag

Comment: @KKO you need to take care of performance. As far as I used, I did not find any lag.

Comment: i don't remember for sure what i did, but i think that after i disabled hardwareAccelerated it started running smoothly

Comment: hyy, i used your code but in design not set Scanner in center .. can you give me a advise how to set in center 200*200 dp  scanner.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the repeat property

android:repeatMode

int. How an animation behaves when it reaches the end of the animation. android:repeatCount must be set to a positive integer or "-1" for this attribute to have an effect. Set to "reverse" to have the animation reverse direction with each iteration or "repeat" to have the animation loop from the beginning each time.

```
Animation a;
a.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

Comment: it works but leaving a line when moving reverse direction means from bottom to top. How to remove this line so it looks like that it is scanning. I have updated my code and also attached the image. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, define an `anim` XML file like that:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toYDelta="2%p" />
</set>
```

Second, apply it using Kotlin:

```
val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            requireContext(),
            R.anim.anim
        )


        binding.yourView.animation = anim
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to remove `mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);` because this means that it will stay permanently where it stops.

In order to return to the initial position, either you can make a complete animation set for both moving up and down, or make two separate and when the first finish, then start the second, although there is no reason to follow such an approach.

Comment: I have made what I want but now I am getting the new problem for which I have attached an image. I have updated my question. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**This is works better for continuously move image up to down.**

```
TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1f, TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f);
                        mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
                        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
                        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
                        mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
imgeview.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```