# How to create a looping animation by continuous translating an image?

Tags: android, android-animation

By using a repeating image like this,

[image: repeating image]

is it possible to create animation like this?

[image: looping animation]

Answer (score 15):

I figured it out

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int screenWidth = getScreenDimensions(this).x;
        final int waveImgWidth = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wave).getIntrinsicWidth();
        int animatedViewWidth = 0;
        while (animatedViewWidth < screenWidth) {
            animatedViewWidth += waveImgWidth;
        }
        animatedViewWidth += waveImgWidth;


        View animatedView = findViewById(R.id.animated_view);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) animatedView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = animatedViewWidth;
        animatedView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        Animation waveAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -waveImgWidth, 0, 0);
        waveAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        waveAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        waveAnimation.setDuration(2500);

        animatedView.startAnimation(waveAnimation);
    }

    public static Point getScreenDimensions(Context context) {
        int width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        return new Point(width, height);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/animated_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:background="@drawable/wave_repeating_bg" />

</FrameLayout>
```

wave_repeating_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/wave"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

drawable-xxhdpi/wave.jpg:
[image]

Comment: It's good that you figured it out by yourself! However, we don't really encourage "code-only" answer. If you have time, please explain some of the logic on the code for future readers, thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for this! I've tried modifying the `animationViewWidth` to get an animation that does not span the screen width, but I am experiencing problems. Are you familiar with a good way of doing things? Weighting the layouts in the XML is overidden by the java routine.

Comment: I used this as well and using the FrameLayout is important, it would not work for me with a RelativeLayout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

bottom to top infinite animation i implement this way. it's too easy just use two image and animated one after another.

> Inside MainActivity.java

```
        imageView_background1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_background1);
        imageView_background1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView_background1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1f);
        mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        imageView_background1.setAnimation(mAnimation);

        imageView_background2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_background2);
        imageView_background2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation mAnimation1 = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
        mAnimation1.setDuration(10000);
        mAnimation1.setRepeatCount(-1);
        mAnimation1.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        mAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        imageView_background2.setAnimation(mAnimation1);
```

> Inside activity_main.xml (use same image both imageview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_splash_background">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_background1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_splash_categories" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_background2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_splash_categories" />
</FrameLayout>
```