# How can I create a moving background image in an activity in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a background image in an activity. I want my background image 
to move continuously like live wallpaper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question but I think what you are asking for a `ViewFlipper`. Can you add an illustration of what you expect your output to be?

Comment: i want my background image to move continuously in the activity like live wallpaper

Comment: look at this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281276/how-to-move-image-up-and-down-continuously-using-translate-animation-in-android)

Comment: and this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894384/android-move-background-continuously-with-animation)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but I don't understand your question...You want to move your background image from activity to another by pressing a button?

Comment: i want my background image to move continuously in the activity like live wallpaper.

Comment: So you want that this image to have an animation that makes it move in the background?